# NodeMCU don't connect to web-site

Tags: http, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm trying to connect my NodeMCU V3 (based on ESP8266) to `http://ya.ru` by this code:

```lua
station_cfg={}
station_cfg.ssid="ssid" -- actual ssid was here
station_cfg.pwd="password" -- and password
server_link = "http://ya.ru"

wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config(station_cfg)
wifi.sta.connect()

http.put(server_link,
  'hi',
  function(code, data)
    print(code)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      print(code, data)
    end
  end)
```

But the connection is not successful, output is:

```
HTTP client: Response too long (8461)
```

What can be wrong? SSID and password are correct. The same problem is with all `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` methods.

UPD:
Hmm, all works fine with the same script written on the C language in Arduino IDE. Anyway, it's strange for me that Lua interpreter can't do such requests but version compiled from C can.

Answer (score 0):

> What can be wrong?

The HTTP module is actually quite precise in telling you what's wrong.

```
HTTP client: Response too long (8461)
```

The response is too long. And *too* long in this context means: longer than it can handle. Looks like you need to resort to using the low-level `net:socket:send()` as per https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/net/#netsocketsend